# i want to restrict route access based on role

Tags: angular6, ionic4

i want to provide role based route access e.g there is two types of user 1.Admin and 2.normal user.
if normal user try to access admin pages through url then user will redirects to dashboard page and same case for admin.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a lot of code you're asking for.

One thing you need to look into is Route Guards which let you protect access to routes based on your own written criteria:

- https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

You also need to pick a way to manage your roles and users. A popular way for Ionic is to use Firebase:

- https://firebase.google.com/

A great tutorial for setting this all up is over at AngularFirebase.com (currently rebranding to Fireship.io).

It's a long tutorial, and you will need to follow an additional tutorial for setting up the login system as well, but it will get you to where you want to be.

- [Role Based Authorization With Firestore and Angular](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/role-based-authorization-with-firestore-nosql-and-angular-5/)

Comment: is there  any other way to do it because i am not using firebase and i am very new to ionic

Comment: I suggested Firebase because it seemed like you are new to this. Making your own system is a lot harder than learning how to integrate Firebase. You have to do the auth on the server side for it to be secure so if you want to do it yourself you need to learn some other technologies. Using Firebase lets you do it all through a Typescript API.